# unable to compile cuda code, compiling error

Tags: cuda, compilation

I'm getting an error when i try to compile and build cuda code

> error C2065: 'threadIdx' : undeclared identifier
>
> error C2228: left of '.x' must have class/struct/union

Comment: Post your kernel code and build commands - otherwise it's going to be hard to tell where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

simply try changing the extension of your main *.cpp file to *.cu (other than the kernel file which must be *.cu)